# Error TS en angular no reconoce ninguna propiedad ni ningún modulo de la aplicación

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angular, typescript, modulos

Estoy realizando una aplicacion con angular y todo estaba bien , pero de un momento al otro abrí vs code y cargué mi proyecto y ahora vs code no me reconoce ningún modulo ni tampoco ninguna propiedad en todas los componentes de mi aplicacion , si bien mi aplicacion funciona y no me genera ningun error es un poco molesto trabajar con tantas lineas rojas marcando errores que no existen.
Ya intente remover los modulos de node y volverlos a instalar y no funciono quisiera saber si saben como solucionar el problema adjunto imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Se encuentran declarados con `@NgModule`, estas usando lazy loading?

Comment: PD: El error sobre `"Experimental decorators"` pese a que `VSCode` lo marca como error es simplemente una alerta, pues enrealidad no tiene peso alguno en el codigo, sobre lo de `Cannot Find Module`... puede ser un error muy estupido realmente, puede ser que hayas abierto el `VSCode` pero no en la carpeta raiz del proyecto, por eso no encuentra esos modulos, pero a la hora de compilar no da errores y te permite trabajar, simplemente hace alusion a caracteristicas cambiantes con las que debes tener cuidado.

Comment: Por si acaso intenta cerrar tu visual studio code y abrelo de nuevo en el directorio raiz de tu proyecto, de una vez vuelve a intentar compilar.

Comment: ¿Has intentado eliminar la carpeta `node_modules` y volver a instalar los paquetes mediante `npm install` ?